# Selecting rows from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create a web index. Every advertiser in my database will be able to appear on a few categories, so I've added a `categorys` column, and in that column I'll store the categories separated by "," so it will look like:

```
1,3,5
```

The problem is that I have no idea how I'm supposed to select all of the advertisers in a certain category, like: `mysql_query("SELECT * FROM advertisers WHERE category = ??");`

Comment: `and in that column il store the categories seperated by "," `  It would be better to normalize these into a separate table.

Answer (score 3):

If `categories` is another database table, you shouldn't use a plain-text field like that.  Create a "pivot table" for the purpose, something like `advertisers_categories` that links the two tables together.  With setup, you could do a query like:

```
SELECT A.* FROM advertisers AS A
JOIN advertisers_categories AS AC ON AC.advertiser_id = A.id
WHERE AC.category_id = 12;
```

The schema of `advertisers_categories` would look something like this:

```
# advertisers_categories
# --> id INT
# --> advertiser_id INT
# --> category_id INT
```

Comment: +1 for including the query (I couldn't remember for the life of me how to join the tables XD)

Comment: @Ben If you like it, accept the answer. :)  Judging from the 1 rep, I imagine you're just starting here.

Answer (score 1):

You should design your database in another way. Take a look at [Atomicity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form#Atomicity).
**Short**: You should not store your value in the form of 1,3,5.

I won't give you an answer because if you starting you use it this way **now**, you going to run into much more severe problems **later**. No offense :)

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible having comma-separated values to do this strictly in an SQL query. You could return *every* row and have a PHP script which goes through each row, using `explode($row,',')` and then `if(in_array($exploded_row,'CATEGORY'))` to check for the existence of the category.

The more common solution is to restructure your database. You're thinking too two-dimensionally. You're looking for the [Many to Many Data Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_%28data_model%29)

```
advertisers
-----------
id
name
etc.

categories
----------
id
name
etc.

ad_cat
------
advertiser_id
category_id
```

So ad_cat will have at least one (usually more) entry per advertiser and at least one (usually more) entry per category, and every entry in ad_cat will link one advertiser to one category.

The SQL query then involves grabbing every line from ad_cat with the desired category_id(s) and searching for an advertiser whose id is in the resulting query's output.

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation as-is will make it difficult and taxing on your server's resources to do what you want.

I'd recommend creating a table that relates advertisers to categories and then querying on that table given a category id value to obtain the advertisers that are in that category.

Answer (score 0):

That is a **very wrong** way to define categories, because your array of values cannot be normalized.
Instead, define another table called CATEGORIES, and use a JOIN-table to match CATEGORIES with ADVERTIZERS.

Only then you will be able to properly select it.

Hope this helps!